# JavaScript Constructor change the value

Tags: javascript

I have a question that is probably really easy for all of you.

For example, I got the following constructor

```
class Example {
   constructor(product, total) {
       this.product= product;
       this.total= total;
   }
}
```

How can I now change the value of the product for example to apple?

I am thankful for any help.

Comment: `this.product = 'apple'`?

Comment: Instantiate an apple: `var apple = new Example('apple')`

Comment: What do you exactly intend by change? Change after instantiating ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Example {
   constructor(product, total) {
    this.product= product;
    this.total= total;
   }
}

let exampleObj = new Example('apple')
console.log(exampleObj.product) // 'apple'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways in which you can set the value `apple`. The recommended way is set the value apple at the time of initialization like this:

```js
class Example {
   constructor(product, total) {
    this.product= product;
    this.total= total;
   }
}
//set the value apple at the time of initialization
var example = new Example('apple', '10');
console.log(example.product);
```

Set the value `apple` after initialization:

```js
class Example {
   constructor(product, total) {
    this.product= product;
    this.total= total;
   }
}
//set the value apple at the time of initialization
var example = new Example();
example.product = 'apple';
console.log(example.product);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your class `Example`

```
class Example {
   constructor(product, total) {
      this.product= product;
      this.total= total;
   }
}
```

Now you can create object instances of this class like this:

```
var product1 = new Example('apple', 0); 
var product2 = new Example('banana', 0);
```

Increment the amount of apples and print the total:

```
product1.total++;
console.log(product1.product + ': ' + product1.total);
```